# Why does (I have to get together with someone) sound clumsy?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

As an English learner, I don't see anything wrong with this sentence:

> I have to get together with Jóse soon.

This translation from Spanish is suggested by Duolingo. In case any of you know about Spanish, here is the original sentence:

> Tengo qué quedar con Jóse pronto.

Someone claimed that the translation (in English) above sounds clumsy, however, I don't remember what he/she suggested as the appropriate sentence that is likely spoken by native speakers. He/she is British native speaker, by the way. I can't provide the link since the comment section is random unless I leave a comment and get notified by E-mail.

Anyway, can you tell me why this sentence sounds clumsy? And what is the proper sentence that's likely to use in English?

Comment: I don't speak Spanish, but Google Translate gives "I have to **meet** José". _Get together with_ can mean to meet someone by arrangement. Maybe they thought _José and I have to get together soon_ would be better?

Comment: 'Get together with' is informal, and may be considered 'clumsy' in some contexts. 'Meet' is more formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the phrase *get together with*. It is slightly informal and more usual would be *meet*. Having said that the Spanish word *quedar* implies to me that you are actually going to sit down somewhere with Jose and have a chat which fits slightly better with *get together with* than with *meet*.